# GoogleMobileAds.framework 7.25.0-7.26.0 issue

Tags: ios, swift, ads, admob

Taking a look at GoogleMobileAds.framework 7.25.0 or 7.26.0, the "Versions" directory is missing. 
You can see on the left is 7.25.0 and to the left is 7.24.1

When using the >7.25.0 I get a error because of this.  Is there a setting I have to do to support this new framework.  And no, I don't want to use CocoaPods.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the latest Google SDK fixed the issue and you will need to clear Derived data to make sure it is working properly.